# Trying to get better approach for simple image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple gallery that hides and show images. It works fine however I am not satisfy with my approach. My javascript seemed redundant. Can you check my code and give better idea on how can I improve it.

This is my html

```
<div class="big_img_wrapper">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_1.JPG" id="big_img_1" class="big_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_2.JPG" id="big_img_2" class="big_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_3.JPG" id="big_img_3" class="big_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_4.JPG" id="big_img_4" class="big_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_5.JPG" id="big_img_5" class="big_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/big_img_6.JPG" id="big_img_6" class="big_img">
                </div>
                <div class="thumbs_img_wrapper">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_1.jpg" id="thumbs_img_1" calss="thumbs_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_2.jpg" id="thumbs_img_2" calss="thumbs_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_3.jpg" id="thumbs_img_3" calss="thumbs_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_4.jpg" id="thumbs_img_4" calss="thumbs_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_5.jpg" id="thumbs_img_5" calss="thumbs_img">
                    <img src="<?= IMAGEPATH ?>front_page/phinfo/house_rentals/westgate/thumbnails/thumbs_img_6.jpg" id="thumbs_img_6" calss="thumbs_img">
                </div>
```

This is my css

```
.big_img_wrapper, .big_img_wrapper img{
            width: 370px;
            height: 246px;
            /*display: none;*/
        }
        .thumbs_img_wrapper{
            padding:0;
        }
        .thumbs_img_wrapper img{
            width: 111px;
            height: 70px;
            margin: 14px 0 0 14px;
        }
        #thumbs_img_1, #thumbs_img_4{
            margin: 14px 0 0 0;
        }
```

And finally here's my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
    $('img#big_img_1').fadeIn('slow'); // Serve as default image

    $('img#thumbs_img_1').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_1').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });

    $('img#thumbs_img_2').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_2').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });

    $('img#thumbs_img_3').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_3').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
    $('img#thumbs_img_4').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_4').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
    $('img#thumbs_img_5').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_5').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
    $('img#thumbs_img_6').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        $('img#big_img_6').fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });

});
```

I'm willing to use plugins for better improvements.
Thanks!

Comment: Given the nature of the question it may be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I already uploaded it to codereview. Here is the link. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69706/trying-to-get-better-approach-for-simple-image-gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using .click() event for each thumbnail you can use:

```
$('img.thumbs_img').click(function(){
        $('img.big_img').hide(); // Hides all big images
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace("thumbs_img_", "big_img_");
        $('img#'+id).fadeIn('slow'); //Slowly fades in selected image
    });
```

still not sure if that is better.

Comment: Good solution, but you have to improve the selection of the big img. your id you get is the id of the thumb like `thumbs_img_3` and you have to select `$(img# + big_img_3` and not `$(img# + thumbs_img_3` to fade it in. Maybe with something like `id.replace("thumbs", "big")`

Comment: didn't notice that, editing for better solution right away. :)

Comment: Last change: `id = str.replace` should be `id = id.replace` i think. After that i thinks its pretty nice.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried your code and it didn't work.

Comment: @Rodge - can it be because of the html syntax : `calss="thumbs_img"` that should be `class=` ?

Comment: What doesnt work? Maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2kpfvq5/) helps. Semms to work pretty fine. (On the point, that we dont have the images)

Comment: Yah! Thanks again and sorry for my typo errors. The problem now comes when I clicked on the small image, the large one disappear and didn't show the other one.

Comment: Check if you used the `id = id.replace` or `id = str.replace` version of the code. The first one is correct!

Comment: Cool! It worked. I replace id = str.replace to id = id.replace and works fine. Thanks guys for your great solutions. I really appreciate it.